# Как создать проект из уже существующих файлов с кодом?

Tags: c, codeblocks

Добрый день,

Имею набор файлов *.c* и *.h* . Мне их нужно скоспилировать и протестировать в CodeBlocks. Создаю пустой проект, добавляю туда все эти файлы, но при компиляции выкидывает в какой-то заголовочный файл **errors.h** (его у меня нет в наборе), пишет ошибку:

```
error: unkown type name 'DWORD'
```

и  указывает на эту строку в этом **errors.h** :

```
DWORD WINAPI AMGetErrorTextA(HRESULT,CHAR*,DWORD);
```

Спасибо за ответы!

Comment: А включен ли <Windows.h>?

Answer (score 0):

Судя по всему нужно подключить библиотеку quartz и заголовочный файл dshow.h.
Посмотрел у себя в папке mingw - все эти файлы есть, значит в codeblocks должны быть, там вроде тоже mingw компилятор.

Comment: Это обычный заголовочник Windows SDK, при чем тут quartz?

Comment: Внезапно в Requirements https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373430(v=vs.85).aspx